# troubleshooting .net 5.0 modelmapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, modelmapper

I'm porting an application using REST APIs based on OwinSelfHost from .NET 4.7 to net5.0 (and thus ASP.Net Core)

I've got it mostly working, CRUD operations on my objects are working at first glance. But I have other operations where I'm using POST and that fail because the model mapper cannot map properties.

Here's what I get if I intercept the request before the controller

> POST https://localhost:8189/api/SystemLanguage/UI Headers:
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> {"id":"fdc09070-c144-4f66-a5a7-2c802ac64765"}

The controller looks like this

```
public class MyController<IdUIExtractionParameters>: ControllerBase where TUIExtraction class, IUIExtractionParameters
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UI")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUi(IdUIExtractionParameters uiParameters)
    {
     ... stripped for brevity
    }
}

public class IdUIExtractionParameters
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
}
```

If I set logging to Trace, I can see this

> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder[22]
> Attempting to bind parameter 'uiParameters' of type 'AUDMService.Models.IdUIExtractionParameters' ...
> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexObjectModelBinder[44]
> Attempting to bind parameter 'uiParameters' of type 'AUDMService.Models.IdUIExtractionParameters' using the name '' in request data ...
> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[13]
> Attempting to bind property 'AUDMService.Models.IdUIExtractionParameters.Id' of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]' using the name 'Id' in request data ... dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[15] Could not find a value in the request with name 'Id' for binding property 'AUDMService.Models.IdUIExtractionParameters.Id' of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]'.
> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.SimpleTypeModelBinder[14]
> Done attempting to bind property 'AUDMService.Models.IdUIExtractionParameters.Id' of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Guid]'.

And I'm stumped as to why.. it clearly finds a parameter with id. I know it's not case sensitivity because I have other POST's that work fine when they get camelCase data. I don't think it's the generics either because the Create in CRUD also uses a generic parameter for the object to be added.

Note that I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for JSON serialization/deserialization because my app uses some very specifig things that aren't yet in System.Text.Json

From my Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter(new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCaseNamingStrategy()));
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Any idea why the model mapper is not picking up IdUIExtractionParameters.Id? I'm also having problems with other parameters to MyController. What's common is that the properties that remain empty are nullable.

@edit: been experimenting some more. For test purposes, I went with System.Text.Json, but same experience. I got rid of the generics, same issue. Made Id non nullable, and now I'm ending up with Guid.Empty.

And then, Eureka, my Google KungFu finally yielded the response: add a `[FromBody]` to `uiParameters` and it maps things just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out the solution was so easy. Most of my controller methods use `[FromBody]` tags before the mapped models. And that's all it took.